# Unable to Create Generic Function to Register Multiple cell at once

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, generics

I am trying to create a method to register multiple cell at once to a table view using Reusable Protocol but I am facing some error Here is my Code

```
func register<T>(cells: [T.Type]) where T: UITableViewCell & NibReusable {
        cells.forEach { cellType in
            self.register(cellType: cellType)
        }
}

 tableView.register(cells: [SimpleHeaderView.self]) // Code Compile Successfully 

 tableView.register(cells: [SimpleHeaderView.self, AccountInfoCell.self]) // Getting Error Cannot invoke 'register' with an argument list of type '(cells: [BaseTableViewCell.Type])'
```

Getting Error **Cannot invoke 'register' with an argument list of type '(cells: [BaseTableViewCell.Type])'**

Comment: Check if `AccountInfoCell` conforms to `NibReusable`

Comment: @fewlinesofcode, I already checked that one. It Confirm to same `base class` and `Nibreusable`

Comment: Please, share `NibReusableView` protocol code

Comment: @fewlinesofcode it is simple protocol. you could find at https://github.com/AliSoftware/Reusable

Comment: Any update on that